# Rails: multiple models operating on same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

I'm building a system that has some records in tables that are template records, which are viewable by all accounts and can be later copied to create live records for an individual account.

The reasoning behind this design decision is that template records and live records share 95%+ of the same code, so I didn't want to create a separate table to track mostly the same fields.

For instance, I have a `workflows` table:

- id:integer
- account_id:integer
- name:string (required)
- is_a_template:boolean (default: false)
- is_in_template_library:boolean (default: false)

In this table, I have some records that are templates.  When I go to create a new live record, I can use a template record:

```
# workflows_controller.rb (pseudo-code, not fully tested)
def create
  @workflow_template = Workflow.where(is_a_template: true).find_by(id: params[:workflow_template_id])
  @workflow = current_account.workflows.new(workflow_params.merge(@workflow_template.dup))

  if @workflow.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

As I build more functionality, I find that I really need 2 different models that operate differently on the table.  There are several more differences, but those listed below are enough to show the differences:

```
class Workflow < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope -> { where(is_a_template: false) }

  belongs_to :account

  validates :account, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true
end

class WorkflowTemplate < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope -> { where(is_a_template: true) }

  validates :name, presence: true
end

class WorkflowLibraryTemplate < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope -> { where(is_a_template: true, is_in_template_library: true) }

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

As you can see, the `workflows` table has 3 different "types" of records:

1. "live" workflows that belong to an account
2. template workflows that also belong to an account and are copied to create "live" workflows
3. library template workflows that do NOT belong to an account and can be viewed by any account, so they can copy them into their own list of templates

**Question**

What I'm trying to figure out, is at what point do I break up this single table into multiple tables, versus keeping the same table and having multiple models, or what solution is there to a problem like this?

The frustrating part is that there are 5+ other tables that are "children" associations of the `workflows` table.  So if I decide that I need separate tables for each, I would end up going from 6 tables to something like 18, and everytime I add a field, I have to do it to all 3 "versions" of the table.

Thus I'm very reluctant to go down the multiple tables route.

If I keep a single table and multiple models, I then end up with different version of data in the table, which isn't the end of the world.  I only interact with the data through my application (or a future API I control).

Another solution I'm thinking about is adding a `role:string` field to the table, which operates very much like the `type` field in Rails.  I didn't want to use STI, however, because there are too many baked-in requirements with Rails that I don't want to conflict with.

What I'm envisioning is:

```
class Workflow < ApplicationRecord
  scope :templates, -> { where(role: "template") }
  scope :library_templates, -> { where(role: "library_template") }

  validates :account, presence: true, if: :account_required?
  validates :name, presence: true

  # If record.role matches one of these, account is required
  def account_required
    ["live", "template"].include?(role.to_s.downcase)
  end
end
```

This seems to address several of the issues, keeps me with 1 table and 1 model, but begins to have conditional logic in the model, which seems like a bad idea to me as well.

Is there a cleaner way to implement a templating system within a table?

Comment: Any particular difficulties you're encountering or expect to encounter with your current approach?

Comment: What I have in production right now is a bunch of conditional logic that's pretty ugly.  If I go with an STI approach, I'll have to create several different model files that implement the logic for each one separately.  I think that's easier to maintain than multiple tables, though. The big problem with going STI is that I'll have to have separate model files for all the associations as well, which would add 10+ model files.

Answer (score 5):

So what you are looking at here is called [Single Table Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance). The models are called [polymorphic](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2017/08/16/polymorphic-associations-in-rails.html).

As far as when to break up the STI into distinct tables, the answer is: when you have enough divergence that you start having specialized columns. The problem with STI is that let's say WorkFlows and WorkFlowTemplate start to diverge. Maybe the template starts getting a lot of extra attributes as columns that do not correspond to plain old workflows. Now you have lots of data that is empty for one class (or not needed) and useful and necessary for the other. In this case, I'd probably break the tables apart. The real question you should ask is:

1. How far will these models diverge from each other in terms of requirements?
2. How soon will this happen?

If it happens very late in the life of my app:

Will it be difficult/impossible to migrate these tables due to how many rows/how much data I have?

Edit:

Is there a cleaner way? In this specific case, I don't think so given a template and a copy of that template, are likely to be tightly coupled to each other.

Comment: The records will always be 95%+ similar; if the templates ever become drastically different, then I would break them into their own resource, but I can't ever see that happening.  At the moment, they only differ in `account_id, is_a_template, is_in_template_library`, which if I use a "role/type" field, that would collapse the template fields.  I'm ok with 2-3 different fields, and I don't see that ever going beyond 5, but I can't always tell the future :)

Comment: Exactly. I would also add: leave yourself room. Metz says if you can avoid making a decision, do so, punt the decision if you can.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I took is decomposition by responsibility.

**Decomposition by responsibility**:

Right now, you have 3 different sources of data and 2 different ways to create/validate a workflow.

In order to achieve that, you can introduce the concept of `Repositories` and `FormObject`s.

Repositories are wrapper objects that will abstract the way you query your model. It doesn't care if it is the same table or multiple. It just knows how to get the data.

For example:

```
class Workflow < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
end

class WorkflowRepository
  def self.all
    Workflow.where(is_a_template: false)
  end
end

class WorkflowTemplateRepository
  def self.all
    Workflow.where(is_a_template: true)
  end
end

class WorkflowLibraryTemplateRepository
  def self.all
    Workflow.where(is_a_template: true, is_in_template_library: true)
  end
end
```

This makes sure that no matter what you decide in the future to do, you will not change other parts of the code.

So now let's discuss `FormObject`

`FormObject` will abstract the way you validate and build your objects. It might not be a great addition right now but usually, pays off in the long run.

For example

```
class WorkFlowForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor(
    :name,
    :another_attribute,
    :extra_attribute,
    :account
  )

  validates :account, presence: true
  validates :name, presence: true

  def create
    if valid?
      account.workflows.create(
        name: name, is_a_template: false,
        is_in_template_library: false, extra_attribute: extra_attribute)
    end
  end
end

class WorkflowTemplateForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor(
    :name,
    :another_attribute,
    :extra_attribute
  )

  validates :name, presence: true

  def create
    if valid?
      Workflow.create(
        name: name, is_a_template: true,
        is_in_template_library: false, extra_attribute: extra_attribute)
    end
  end
end

class WorkflowLibraryTemplateForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor(
    :name,
    :another_attribute,
    :extra_attribute
  )

  validates :name, presence: true

  def create
    if valid?
      Workflow.create(
        name: name, is_a_template: true,
        is_in_template_library: true, extra_attribute: extra_attribute)
    end
  end
end
```

This approach helps with extendability as everything is a separate object.
The only drawback of that is that In my humble opinion, WorkflowTemplate and WorkflowLibraryTemplate are semantical the same thing with an extra boolean but that's an optional thing you can take or leave.